# Solve the equation in integers numbers $3x^2-2xy-7=y^2$.

Tags: polynomials, exponentiation

**PROBLEM:**

Solve the equation in integers numbers $3x^2-2xy-7=y^2$.

**WHAT I THOUGHT OF:**

What if we pass $y^2$ to the other member of the equality.

> $3x^2-2xy-7-y^2=0$

Forward it would be simple if we can write  $3x^2-2xy-7-y^2$ as a product of 2 equations. I need help here, because i thought a lot about how can i rewrite it. Also, abbreviated calculation formulas might help. Hope one of you can help me!

Comment: I suggest, rewrite as $3\left(x-\frac y3\right)^2-7=cy^2$ for the appropriate constant $c)$ and then change variable to get to the form $AX^2+B=CY^23.

Comment: @lulu Can you re-write the comment, because I don't understand?

Comment: There was a typo at the end, the "3" was meant to be a dollar sign.  Thus $AX^2+B=CY^2$.  But the method in the posted solution, full factoring, is better anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that by moving $y^2$ to the $LHS$, we can factorise as $(x - y)(3x + y) = 7$. I typically spot these kinds of factorisations by considering the case $y = 1$; alternatively, you can use the fact that it can be rewritten as $(x - y)^2 + 2(x^2 - y^2)$, from which the factorisation is more readily apparent.

Since $x$, $y$ are integers, it follows these brackets are integers. Hence, we must have either
\begin{align*}
x - y = -7&, 3x + y = -1 &&\implies (x, y) = (-2, 5)\\
x - y = -1&, 3x + y = -7 &&\implies (x, y) = (-2, -1)\\
x - y = 1&, 3x + y = 7 &&\implies (x, y) = (2, 1)\\
x - y = 7&, 3x + y = 1 &&\implies (x, y) = (2, -5)
\end{align*}
Hence, all solutions are $(-2, 5), (-2, -1), (2, 1), (2, -5)$.

Comment: Oooo....this makes sense right now! Thank you so much!

Comment: The key point of the question is just to factorise $(x-y)(3x+y)=7$ . Calculations are routine here . This could be e.g. $$(x-y+1)(2y+x+3)=10.$$ As a side note, WA gives the above factorization directly. I would not agree the key point of the question just to state "we can factorise as....". We can observe. But how ?This does not imply, your answer is not nice, but what I mean the key idea of the solution need some expansion for future readers . Thanks.

Comment: @lonestudent I've added a couple of sentences explaining how to come about with the factorisation.

Answer (score 0):

First, $3x^2−2xy−7−y^2$ isn't an equation: that's an expression. $3x^2−2xy−7−y^2 = 0$ is an equation.

Now let's say you want to write $3x^2−2xy−7−y^2$ as a product of two expressions.
You can start by looking for any solutions, integer or not, complex or not.

Here, notice that if you fix y you have a nice 2nd degree polynomial in x: $ax^2+bx+c=0$ (with $a=3$, $b=-2y$, $c=-7-y^2$).

Just apply the formula for discriminant: $\Delta = b^2-4ac = 4y^2+12(7+y^2) = 16y^2+84$

$\Delta > 0$, so $\frac {-b+\sqrt{\Delta} }{2a}$ and $\frac {-b-\sqrt{\Delta} }{2a}$ are roots: $3x^2−2xy−7−y^2 = (x-\frac {-b+\sqrt{\Delta} }{2a})(x-\frac {-b-\sqrt{\Delta} }{2a}) = (x-\frac {y+\sqrt{4y^2+21} }{3})(x-\frac {y-\sqrt{4y^2+21} }{3})$

And thus, the equation $3x^2−2xy−7−y^2 = 0$ is equivalent to $(x-\frac {y+\sqrt{4y^2+21} }{3})(x-\frac {y-\sqrt{4y^2+21} }{3}) = 0$

You could have done the same thing by fixing x instead of y, and that would have given you a different result (but the same set of solutions).

Answer (score 0):

$3x^{2}-2xy-7=y^{2}$  then  $(\sqrt{3} x)^{2} +(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} y)^{2} -(1+\frac{1}{3})y^{2}-2xy-7=0$

i.e $7=(\sqrt{3} x -\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} y -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} y)(\sqrt{3} x -\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} y +\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} y)=(x-y)(3x+y)$  then ,
1).if $x-y=1$ then $3x+y=7$ conclution solution is $(x,y)=(2,1)$ and  if $x-y=7$ then $3x+y=1$ then solution,$(x,y)=(2,-5)$

$x-y=-1$ then $3x+y=-7$
Solution:$(x,y)=(-2,-1)$

$x-y=-7$ then $3x+y=-1$
Solution:$(x,y)=(-2,5)$

then solution general is $(x,y)=\{(-2,-1),(-2,5),(2,1),(2,-5)\}$.

Comment: There are 2 more situations: if $x-y=-7$ and if $x-y=-1$. Anyways, thank you soo much for your answer!